# Checking for characters in an input

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently creating a GUI binary to denary and denary to binary converter. 
For the input of the binary to denary part I created an if statement which checks for numbers other than 1 and 0 in the input, however its ability to check for the wrong characters is unpredictable and doesn't produce reliable results, or at least to me they seem unreliable.

If anyone can suggest a better method to checking for charcters or can tell me what is wrong with mine it would be massively appreciated.

```
BToDInput=input("Enter the Binary string ")
if (("2" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7" or "8" or "9") in BToDInput):
    print("invalid character")
else:
    print("character accepted")
```

here is a screenshot of the code being ran. This code should only accept 1's and 0's to be inputted, however as you can see from the picture it is not consistent and allows inputs through randomly. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For validating the contents of a binary string, it's probably best to use a regular expression:

```
#Python regular expression library
import re

#Get as raw input, so we can process as a string later
BToDInput = raw_input("Enter the Binary string ")

#This searches for any character in the string that is not (denoted by the ^) in the range 0 - 1 (deonted by [0-1])
#If the search returns an empty list (None), then we know that the string contains nothing but 1's and 0's
if re.search("[^0-1]", BToDInput) == None:
    print("character accepted")
else:
    print("invalid character")
```

If you're going to be doing more string processing, definitely read up on Python's regular expression library: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you yes it did help, only thing wrong with it was the "raw_input" as this was replaced with "input" in python 3, but apart from that the re.search works perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear it works! Regular expressions are really helpful once you get the hang of them :)